# How to Create MassTransit Message Interceptor (Observer) with Scoped Lifetime

Tags: masstransit

We can setup `Consume Observer` using following way

```
busControl.ConnectConsumeObserver(container.GetInstance<MessageConsumerInterceptor>());
```

I want to apply Scope lifestyle to MessageConsumerInterceptor so that I can fill/ initialize some object before consuming or handling the message. And I can access that filled object through the message handler or consumer. Now how I can achieve this using MassTransit?

I am expecting your help or possible suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Observer is a not good candidate for this. Observers only observe, they should not change any state or have effect on message processing.

What you are looking at is a middleware.

Check this [documentation page](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html) on how to create and apply custom middleware.

You will get the `ConsumeContext` as the `Send` method parameter in your filter and there you can use methods `GetOrAddPayload<T>` and `TryGetPayload` to add something to the context, so you can fetch this data later inside your consumer.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response and help. I also tried with middleware. From my point of view, Consumer and Middleware runs on a different thread so scoped lifecycle may not possible between them. What do you think?

Comment: As far as I know the scope is opened per message, so it should work. Plus, the pipe by definition consists of filters calling each other. Consumer is just one of them. I do not really see why they should be in different scopes.

Comment: I have tried with Middleware-Filter but no luck. It is giving exception that i cannot use Scoped lifetime object outside of context. It is giving following exception

The MyRequestInfo is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.


Is it possible to get any link or sample where scoped life time is implemented? I want to set some value to some object before initiating consumer.

Comment: What do you mean "outside the context"? Middleware operates within the message consume context. It is hard to reason about words without seeing any code. Post your code on github and we can discuss.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I have created a sample test project github.com/hasibul2363/MassTransitTest.git also created a middleware and from there I want to set the value of an object and then later want to access that value from the consumer. I have used Scoped Lifecycle and used SimpleInjector.

My Configuration class
https://github.com/hasibul2363/MassTransitTest/blob/master/Consumer/Program.cs

Middleware
https://github.com/hasibul2363/MassTransitTest/blob/master/Consumer/Middleware/Middleware.cs

Just want to get RequestInfo value to consumer

Comment: @Zimarev, expecting your valuable response, and help. Another thing how I can read sent message data from middleware.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to check now but will do during the weekend.

Comment: @Zimarev, Thank you very much for quick response. Hope you have some time in this weekend and I will get help from you.